# iPhone:How to get real ads showing in iAds banner in iPhone application?

Tags: iphone

I have integrated iAds in my iOS 4.0 application developed using the following tutorial:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/1371/how-to-integrate-iad-into-your-iphone-app

Currently it is showing only Test Banner page. I would like to know how would i get real Ads showing there and what is the procedure to get it. I couldn't find any help on this. Could someone please point me out ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will automatically be filled with read ads once it is released on App Store.

Apple recognize each of your app by the bundle id, hence unlike other ad networks (such as admob), it does not need you to create other stuff.

Similarly, Apple recognize the distribution build and will serve real ads.

Answer (score 1):

The test banner is just to show that you have incorporated the iAd framework correctly into your application. The "real" ads will work automagically when you submit your app to Apple.

Comment: That's cool. So i don't need to do anything extra? What i followed from this link is enough? http://www.raywenderlich.com/1371/how-to-integrate-iad-into-your-iphone-app

Answer (score 1):

I thought you had to do *ALL* of these:

1. Make sure your app shows "test ads" while you are developing it.
2. Make sure you visit iTunesConnect-iAds and turn on iAds.
3. After your app is 'live for sale' then 'real ads' will start showing.

So far, no one here ever mentioned #2.  (Or am I only having to do #2 myself?)   I've never seen #2 as "automatic" as soon as #3 happens.

Also... even after doing 1,2,3...  I have 1 very odd app that is "live for sale" and iAdsConnect is *STILL* claiming it's only showing 100s of no-revenue, test-ads.   Isn't that impossible?  Shouldn't it be displaying "real ads" or "no ads" instead?